# App for a Blogger application

Tags: android, rss, blogger, atom-feed

I want to create an Android Application for a Blogger blog. The content is contributed by some handful of people including me. With all the search that I have done, I am able to find out SAX parser libraries that pull the data and show the content in `WebView` and the like.

I need to be able to save the feed data on the device. When the user requests, sync only the latest content and provide them with the ability to read the content offline. I have the following queries.

1. Is there any official Blogger API Library that I can use to consume the blog entries.
2. Any links on how to store this data for offline reading.
3. If I store the content in an SQLite database, how can I show the images if any in an entry (Need this info once the above two get answered)
4. I think blogger provides feed data as RSS, Atom etc. Which one will be suited for use in a mobile app - the pros and cons of the same will be useful.

Eagerly awaiting interesting replies.
P.S. I know that one can use services like feedly for this functionality, but I want to learn to write an app like this myself and also create a custom app for our blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so far I have not received any answers. So I will just update as an answer whatever I have been able to solve.

1. There is an official Blogger API from Google. You need to add a request to start using it. The usage is capped, but gives a lot of flexibility in terms of using it.
2. I think we can store the content in a local SQLite database for offline reading.
3. No idea on how to work with images inside the blog entry
4. I think we can parse the blogger feed data without any restrictions, just that it won't be as easy as with Blogger API.

Links : https://code.google.com/apis/console, 
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/getting_started